# What are the advantage or disadvantages difference import styles such as module import and * as import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns

I was wondering and kinda confused as to which style of import should i use, till this moment i came across these imports and i'm not sure which on is faster, or if its worth refactoring my codes to use one of these instead of another one
**Type1 :**, (very simple, no problem here):

```
//This is simple and straight forward
import Component from 'Component';
```

**Type2 (This is one of the ones i have some doubt about):**

```
//#definition JavascriptUtils : 
export function a {}
export function b {}
///,2000 more lines
```

Now this can be used in two ways:

```
//#usage JavascriptUtils : 
//1-
import * as JavascriptUtils from 'Utils/JavascriptUtils'
//2-
import {a, b} as JavascriptUtils from 'Utils/JavascriptUtils'
```

Now i'm not sure if there is a difference between **1** or **2** or if there is, should i even care ?, is there that much difference in performance or package size, i do use this utility a lot, so i'd like to know how much advantage way **1** can give me

**Type3:**

```
//#definition UIUtils : 
export const UIUtils = {
    a,
    b,
}

export function a {}
export function b {}

//#usage UIUtils
import {UIUtils} from 'Utils/UIUtils'
```

**Type4:**

```
//#definition UIUtils : 
export const UIUtils = {
    a,
    b,
}

export function a {}
export function b {}

//#definition JSUtils : 
export const JSUtils = {
    c,
    d,
}

export function c {}
export function d {}

//inside utils/index.js
export * from './UIUtils';
export * from './JSUtils';

//#usage UIUtils
import {UIUtils} from 'utils'
import {JSUtils} from 'utils'
```

So this all the different types of import i used until now, i really like to know which one is the best, which one is `faster`, which one causes less `build size` ? or if there is not difference or the difference is small, i'd like to know that as well.
**I specially like to know if i'll notice any big difference in build size if i use `{a} from import` vs `* as utils import`, my utils are more than 2000 line and are used hundred of times throughout the program**
Thanks!

Comment: Relevant docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: @nopassport1 I read through the document but it doesn't answer my question and thats "which import is faster and how much faster and lighter is it", i need something like a benchmark to decide if i should refactor my code or not

Comment: `i'm not sure if there is a difference between 1 or 2` - Well, if you've got more than 2 exported functions in `Utils/JavascriptUtils`, and you're using `import * as JavascriptUtils from 'Utils/JavascriptUtils'`, then of course your bundle size will be higher - especially if you're not using the majority of your exported functions. But things like `webpack` handle all of that for you. 
MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Tree_shaking 
Webpack: https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/ 
Article: https://insights.untapt.com/webpack-import-require-and-you-3fd7f5ea93c0